# How to rename bulk files by regex?

Tags: bash, shell, file, unix, wget

I have a bunch of files spit out from a wget operation. Many have filenames like this:

```
bootstrap.min.css?v=30cad4497c.css
font-awesome.min.css?v=30cad4497c.css
screen.css?v=30cad4497c.css
```

Yes, those are filenames, question marks and equal signs and all.

The reason the `?v=30cad4497.css` stuff appears is known to me. How do I rename all the files to remove everything after the "?" character?

I'm happy to write a few lines of shell script for this, but I don't want to have to bust out python/node/ruby/whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash:

```
for file in *[?]* ; do mv $file ${file%%[?]*} ; done
```

`*[?]*` means match files that contain a question mark in the filename. `${file%%glob}` means strip off all the text matching the glob *at the end* of the string. `${file##glob}` means strip off all the text matching the glob at the beginning of the string. Please note that these are *file globs*, not regexes. File globs are what we often use to match files in bash.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm going to need more information regrettably. What goes in the `*[?]*` exactly? It seems there are placeholders in your example but I'm not sure what to do with them.

Comment: No problem.  `*[?]*` means match files that contain a question mark.  `${file%%glob}` means strip off all the text matching the glob **at the end** of the string.  `${file##glob}` means strip off all the text matching the glob at the beginning of the string.  Please note that these are _file globs_, not regexes.  File globs are what we often use to match files in bash.

Comment: Great explanation -- can I suggest editing it into the body of your answer?

Comment: I got it to work. I'll accept this as the correct answer. @RJHunter yes that's a great idea, the answer body would benefit from this I explanation.

Answer (score 3):

[Danny Daglas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40668280/45375) works well with the specific filenames at hand, but, for general robustness, the **variable references should be *double-quoted*** to ensure that they're used as-is (to protect their values from [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)):

```
for file in *\?* ; do mv "$file" "${file%%\?*}"; done
```

Also note how I've used **`\?` to match a *literal* `?`**, as it is the more direct expression of the intent - although using a character *set* with only a single element (`[?]`) works too.

A note on the [Pattern Matching Notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) used:

- As Danny notes, patterns, although distantly related, are *not* regexes (regular expressions), and the above link to the POSIX specification describes their specific syntax.
- **Patterns are not *only* used in [pathname expansion (globbing)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs), but *also* in [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)**, of which `${file%%\?*}` is an example:

  - `%%` - as opposed to `%` - strips the *longest* suffix from `$file`'s value that matches the *pattern* that follows.
  - At least with the sample input, which only contains a single `?`, stripping the *shortest* suffix via `%` would have worked too (`${file%\?*}`).

Note that **use of a pattern in a parameter expansion such as `%%` is *independent* of pathname expansion (globbing)**, as the following example demonstrates:

```
$ foo='bar'; echo "${foo%a*}"
b  # suffix 'a' followed by any chars. stripped
```

Additionally, **in Bash (and Ksh and Zsh) you can also use patterns on the RHS of the `==` operator** (note that this is not part of the POSIX standard):

```
$ [[ foo == 'f'* ]] && echo YES
YES
```

Note how pattern metacharacters such as `*` must be *unquoted* in order to be recognized as such (the same goes analogously for the [*regex*-matching operator, `=~`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs)).

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you! Absolutely a refinement to the original, with good points and concerns addressed.